# NC MAX Anti-Infantry weapon choices

Tags: planetside-2

Trying to figure out which MAX left hand weapon isn't a shotgun. looked through the wikia and only saw like 6 weapons and they were all shotguns, was pretty sure there were more choices. Are any of them a minigun or anything but a shotgun, just doesn't work for my playstyle. With the low mag and long reload times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NC faction weapons for maxes are all shotguns or variants of the shotgun. That is just how NC maxes are designed to be indoor/ close range clearing monsters.
There are variants of the shotgun that have longer ranges like the  [Mattock](http://planetside.wikia.com/wiki/AF-34_Mattock), but are still easily outranged by TR or VS Maxes.

an NC max will always win close range battles though... so take that as you will.

Comment: that is disappointing

Comment: A little bit, but that is just how the factions were designed to be... NC is all about close range stopping power. their weapons arent very accurate or stable, but hit like a truck.

Comment: yah what i ended up doing was just getting another scattergun for the right arm. little easier to work with as for breaking heavy defenses.

Comment: @Paralytic you can also give the shotguns slug ammo instead of the buckshot to increase its range drastically and make them more like single shot rifles.

Comment: The Falcons can be useful for anti-infantry at any range if your targets are not moving - I know that sounds dumb, but you would be surprised how many infantry kills you get with them.